# Коллекция HashSet

Tags: java

Внутри `HashSet<E>` хранится объект `HashMap<E, Object>`, который и хранит в качестве ключей значения HashSet. Открыл класс HashSet и увидел такое: 
`private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;`
и вот такое

```
public HashSet() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

Получается когда отрабатывает `HashSet()` конструктор, у нас создается объект класса `HashMap`? Можно по подробнее я просто в шоке и не понимаю почему такая связь и что творится :/
Получается наши значения которые мы создаем в данном примере:

```
HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
        hs.add("Sts");
        hs.add("Str");
        hs.add("Vbs");
```

это всё в итоге объект класса `HashMap` который в качестве ключей хранит значения `Sts, Str, Vbs`? Что-то странности какие-то

Comment: А что в этом странного? Алгоритм работы у них одинаковый, только в одном случае элемент - это пара ключ-значение, а в другом просто одиночный объект. Так зачем городить огород, если можно переиспользовать существующий код.
Вот тут достаточно исчерпывающая статья по вашему вопросу:
https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2147-hashset-v-java

Comment: @iksuy а хеш таблица это Hashtable?

Comment: Хэш-таблица - это просто структура данных такая. В данном случае  она реализована она внутри класса `HashMap`

Comment: @iksuy спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @iksuy а где её в той же Idea можно посмотреть? Или просто понимать что это что-то абстрактное?

Comment: Перейдите в реализацию `HashMap` и смотрите. Но я не уверен что вам это нужно. Если хотите понять как это работает, то лучше прочесть для начала википедию про хэш-таблицу или найти в интернете любую подходящую вам статью по этой теме, это одна из базовых структур данных и в целом полезно понимать как она устроена.

Comment: Откройте любую книгу с похожим названием `Алгоритмы и структуры данных`. Нам это все разжевано